Open square bracket in Karate is not written into input field
I need to insert string containing [ symbol into my textbox by using driver.input method. As open square bracket is a special symbol and escaping with \ or / character ("[" or "/[") does not help, I would like to know how to solve the issue.
My string is returned from JS script as an array with lines separated by Key.ENTER value to preserve new lines as "\n" symbol also doesn't seem to work with driver.input method.
The array looks like this:
["Some text with [", Key.Enter, "Some text"]

My Karate code:
...
* def formattedContent = karate.call(formatContent, content)
* driver.input("#textarea-container", formattedContent)
...


I also tried version where I can have some more control of text inside .input method (to let's say use replace method):
...
* def formattedContent = karate.call(formatContent, content)
* eval karate.forEach(formattedContent, function(text) { if (text == 'Key.ENTER') { driver.input("#textarea-container", Keys.ENTER) } else {driver.input("#textarea-container", text); } })
...


I can format my string in JS to let's say replace all of "[" with "[" but as I said, in case of open square bracket, the escape symbols are not working or maybe I am just trying bad ones, so my question is how to write "[" symbol into html textbox using driver.input method?
(Page that I am working on is made with JSP so editing .value by JS directly is also not convenient so please try to stick to Karate answers)

Did you have a look at https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#dont-parse-treat-as-raw-text?

That could help but I cannot hardcode my text into triple quotes, I have loads of files that should be read and written into textbox. How can I interpolate my string variable inside
"""
"""
section?
Also I checked it and [ symbol still doesn't appear in triple quotes section

Even using unicodes does not work for open square bracket, code:

driver.input('#textarea-container', "\u005B").
It doesn't print anything but when i use  "]" ("\u005D") it prints it.


do consider contributing code to fix this in karate, in the meantime I wonder if using script() to just set the value of the field as a quoted-string should work

The field that I want to set is actually a JSP variable so I am not sure if JS is able to set it. I can only set innerHtml of display element but variable will be untouched. That is why I leaned into Karate simulating typing into textbox.
